# DirectX12: dxgi dll catastrophic failure when creating IDXGIFactory

Tags: directx, directx-12, dxgi

I'm attempting to initialize an IDXGIFactory4 using the `CreateFactory2` function however this throws out an error:

> onecore\windows\directx\database\helperlibrary\lib\perappusersettingsqueryimpl.cpp(121)\dxgi.dll!00007FFBA0D6D7F8: (caller: 00007FFBA0D4D167) ReturnHr(1) tid(64d8) 8000FFFF Catastrophic failure
> onecore\windows\directx\database\helperlibrary\lib\perappusersettingsqueryimpl.cpp(98)\dxgi.dll!00007FFBA0D6D4D0: (caller: 00007FFBA0D3E221) ReturnHr(2) tid(64d8) 8000FFFF Catastrophic failure
> onecore\windows\directx\database\helperlibrary\lib\directxdatabasehelper.cpp(999)\dxgi.dll!00007FFBA0D6D4FC: (caller: 00007FFBA0D3E221) ReturnHr(3) tid(64d8) 8000FFFF Catastrophic failure

I have not found any similar error messages online.
I have attempted running the function on its own and initializing as a different IDXGIFactory (e.g. IDXGIFactory2) instead but both still lead to the same issue.

```
ComPtr<IDXGIFactory> dxgiFactory;
UINT factoryFlags = DXGI_CREATE_FACTORY_DEBUG;
ThrowIfFailed(CreateDXGIFactory2(factoryFlags, IID_PPV_ARGS(&dxgiFactory)));
```

Comment: What ``HRESULT`` is returned from the ``CreateDXGIFactory2`` function?

Comment: Strangely the ```HRESULT``` is ```S_OK```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the error as you describe it.

There is no real failure, there is no catastrophy, there is no even exception and there is no error code returned to you from the API call. What you are seeing is a glitch in internal API implementation that emits debug output with these strange lines. Apparently it is a small problem in Microsoft's API implementation and the weird format of the message suggests it comes from use of [`wil`](https://github.com/Microsoft/wil) in one the modules: they probably intended to remove this output from Release build of the software but somehow it worked out in a different way and unintended debug output passed through...

The message is likely to correspond to recoverable internal error condition which is then handled and your API call ends up being successful. Nothing to worry about, it's just up to Microsoft to make things cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

These errors happen even with any Blank app straight from the templates (or sample apps from Microsoft Github repos) in Visual Studio 2019 (v16.9.1). It's only annoying, apps never crash nor hang. However, this never happend before.

I hope Microsoft better fix this soon (it's bad for nerves and mental health). You can do nothing about it.